# how do i increment an id based on an enum value

Tags: sql, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have a table for users that includes a default `user_id` column. Additionally, there is a `donator_id` column that is null by default, but I want it to auto-increment in case the `user_type` is set to "donator". Can someone help me achieve this?
**this is the expected results, I wanted a way to make "donator_id" only count users of type donator if else it should be null.

```
| user_id | name     | user_type | donator_id|
| ------- | -------- | --------- | ----------|
| 1       | user     | user      | null      |
| 2       | donator  | donator   | 1         |
| 3       | user2    | user      | null      |
| 4       | donator2 | donator   | 2         |
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for `donator_id` to contain the `user_id` of the donor as a foreign key?

Comment: yes a normalisation redesign seems a good idwa

Comment: we used another table for donators but it seemed complex for us to work with because we aren't working with sql that much we're just doing it for our graduation project

Comment: Sample data is great, but we also need the expected result - i.e. a complete [mcve].

Comment: this is the expected results actually, I wanted a way to make "donator_id" only count users of type donator if else it should be null.

Answer (score 0):

as barmar said a restructring of your table, will helpo you keeptrack, ou can update all tabales and add row when needed

```
CREATE TABLE user_type 
    (`user_type` varchar(9), `usertype_id` int PRIMARY KEY )
;
    
INSERT INTO user_type 
    (`user_type`, `usertype_id`)
VALUES
    ('user', '1'),
    ('donator', '2')
;
```

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`user_id` varchar(7), `name` varchar(8), `id_user_type` int,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_user_type)
        REFERENCES user_type(usertype_id)
        ON Update CASCADE)
;
    
INSERT INTO users
    (`user_id`, `name`,`id_user_type`)
VALUES

    ('1', 'user',1),
    ('2', 'donator',2),
    ('3', 'user2',1),
    ('4', 'donator2',2)
;
```

```
SELECT
  u.`user_id`, u.`name`, ut.user_type
FROM users u JOIN user_type ut  ON ut.usertype_id = u.id_user_type
```

| user_id | name | user_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user | user |
| 3 | user2 | user |
| 2 | donator | donator |
| 4 | donator2 | donator |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/z1ljTcbG)

Much more intresting gets it, when a user can have multiple usertypes
then you would also  add a bridge, that will need to be inserted as well but has many benefits.

```
CREATE TABLE user_type 
    (`user_type` varchar(9), `usertype_id` int PRIMARY KEY )
;
    
INSERT INTO user_type 
    (`user_type`, `usertype_id`)
VALUES
    ('user', '1'),
    ('donator', '2')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`user_id` varchar(7) Primary key , `name` varchar(8))
;
    
INSERT INTO users
    (`user_id`, `name`)
VALUES

    ('1', 'user'),
    ('2', 'donator'),
    ('3', 'user2'),
    ('4', 'donator2')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
CREATE TABLE users_user_type(
`user_id` varchar(7)
  , `id_user_type` int,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_user_type)
        REFERENCES user_type(usertype_id),  
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES users(user_id)
        )
```

```
INSERt INTO users_user_type VALUEs (1,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2),( 4,2)
```

> ```
> Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT
  u.`user_id`, u.`name`, ut.user_type
FROM users u 
  JOIN users_user_type uu ON uu.user_id = u.user_id
  JOIN user_type ut  ON ut.usertype_id = uu.id_user_type
ORDER BY u.user_id
```

| user_id | name | user_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user | user |
| 2 | donator | donator |
| 3 | user2 | user |
| 3 | user2 | donator |
| 4 | donator2 | donator |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HK3Q5-Vu)

Comment: i'm not sure. but, I think the idea is not really clear to me

Comment: zser _taoe has only unique values and a promary key on its id, in the user table you add only the id of the user type. Problem could arrose, if someone is user and donator, then we would us a bridge table, i will add it to the example